# Flatten a JSON Array with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, google-apps-script

i am trying to flatten the following JSON file into an array:

```js
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "IO12345",
  "underName": "John Smith",
  "reservationFor": [{
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Google I/O 2013",
    "startDate": "2013-05-15T08:30:00-08:00",
    "location": "Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103"
  }, {
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Apple I/O 2013",
    "startDate": "2016-05-15T08:30:00-08:00",
    "location": "Evergllades Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103"
  }, {
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Apple I/O 2013",
    "startDate": "2016-05-15T08:30:00-08:00",
    "location": "Evergllades Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103"
  }]
}
```

I want to produce checkboxes with this array.
The problem is I get array indices like this: `@EventReservation.reservationFor@Array.01@Event.location`

which should rather look like:

```
@EventReservation.reservationFor@Array.1@Event.location
```

And I don't understand why this is the case.
My code looks like this:

```js
function toArray(obj, namespace) {
  var result = [];
  var array = obj instanceof Array;
  namespace +=  !array ? "@" + obj["@type"] + "." : "@Array.";
  for (var prop in obj) {    
    if(prop == "@context" || prop == "@type") continue;    
    var value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {  
      namespace += prop;     
      toArray(value, namespace).forEach(function(element) {
        result.push(element);
      });
    }
    else {
      result.push(namespace + prop);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

I am trying around for hours now and i can't figure out a solution so i would appreciate your help a lot. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you are appending to your namespace variable every loop. It doesn't look quite right. Try this instead:

```
function toArray(obj, namespace) {
  var result = [];
  var array = obj instanceof Array;
  namespace +=  !array ? "@" + obj["@type"] + "." : "@Array.";
  for (var prop in obj) {    
    if(prop == "@context" || prop == "@type") continue;    
    var value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {  
      toArray(value, namespace + prop).forEach(function(element) {
        result.push(element);
      });
    }
    else {
     result.push(namespace + prop);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! You have been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

All of these methods work - the times are almost the same.

```
function testFlatten() {  

  let arr2D = [ ... giant array here . . . ];


  let arr3D = [ ... giant array here . . . ];
  
  let startTime, endTime, diffTime;
  
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("-------------------- flat startTime: " + startTime );
  
  flatWithConcat (arr2D);
  flatWithConcat (arr3D);
  
  endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("endTime: " + endTime );  
  diffTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
  console.log("flatWithConcat diffTime: " + diffTime );  
    
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("startTime: " + startTime );
  
  flatWithFlat  (arr2D);
  flatWithFlat  (arr3D);
  
  endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("endTime: " + endTime );  
  diffTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
  console.log("flatWithFlat  diffTime: " + diffTime ); 
    
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("----------------- reduce startTime: " + startTime );

 flatWithReduce  (arr2D);
 flatWithReduce  (arr3D);
 
  endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("endTime: " + endTime );  
  diffTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
  console.log("flatWithReduceRight  diffTime: " + diffTime );   
//   
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("----------------- concat startTime: " + startTime );

 flatRedArrowConcat  (arr2D);
 flatRedArrowConcat  (arr3D);
 
  endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("endTime: " + endTime );  
  diffTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
  console.log("flatWithReduceRight  diffTime: " + diffTime );   
// 
//    
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("----------------- reduce rt startTime: " + startTime );

 flatWithReduceRight  (arr2D);
 flatWithReduceRight  (arr3D);
 
  endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("endTime: " + endTime );  
  diffTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
  console.log("flatWithReduceRight  diffTime: " + diffTime );   
    
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("----------------- map startTime: " + startTime );
  
  flatWithMap  (arr2D);
  flatWithMap  (arr3D);
  
  endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("endTime: " + endTime );  
  diffTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
  console.log("flatWithMap  diffTime: " + diffTime );   
  
}

function flatWithConcat (inArray)  { 
  let newArray = [].concat.apply([], inArray);
//  console.log('Reduce right: ' + JSON.stringify(newArray));
}

function flatWithFlat (inArray)  { 
  let newArray = inArray.flat();
//  console.log('Reduce right: ' + JSON.stringify(newArray));
}

function flatWithReduce (inArray)  {
  let newArray = inArray.reduce(
    function (accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator.concat(currentValue);
    });
//  console.log('flatWithReduce: ' + JSON.stringify(newArray));
}

function flatRedArrowConcat (inArray)  {
  let newArray = inArray.reduce(
    (acc, current) => acc.concat(current));
//  console.log('flatRedArrowConcat: ' + JSON.stringify(newArray));
}

function flatWithReduceRight (inArray)  {
  let newArray = inArray.reduceRight(
    function (accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator.concat(currentValue);
    });
//  console.log('flatWithReduceRight: ' + JSON.stringify(newArray));
}

function flatWithMap (inArray)  {
  let newArray = inArray.map(
    function (e) {
      return e[0];
    });
//  console.log('map: ' + JSON.stringify(newArray)); 
}
```